# Instantiating and random Quaternions

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
void spawnBullet()
{
    float speed = 250f;

    // Spawns the bullet                                       // Gets the point                // Point a diffrent direction every time
    GameObject Temporary_Bullet_Handler = Instantiate(Bullet, attackPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(Random.Range(2.557f, -2.557f), Random.Range(0f, -5.795f), attackPoint.transform.rotation.z) as GameObject);

    // Makes the bullet work
    Temporary_Bullet_Handler.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * 90);

    // Shitty rigidy body
    Rigidbody Temporary_RigidBody = Temporary_Bullet_Handler.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    // Adds the force for the bullet to move
    Temporary_RigidBody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);

    // Kill the bullet
    Destroy(Temporary_Bullet_Handler, 10.0f);
}
```

Can someone help me with Instantiating line of bloody code.

I keep getting an error about **cannot convert type unityengine.Quaternion to unityengine.GameObject** and its been pissing me off for an hour, ive used google (even going to the other pages) to try find the answer and all I've found is noting but crap about vector3's

Comment: It's a **Typo**: your are closing the `Instatiate` too late `)`. Therefore it tries to cast the random quaternion `as GameObject` which obviously makes no sense ;) ... You don't need it **at all** ... `Instantiate` is **generic** and anyway returns the type of given parameter so if `Bullet` is a `GameObject` it will anyway return `GameObject` .. there is no need to cast here

Comment: Also note that in general `attackPoint.transform.rotation.z` will return unexpected results! A Quaternion has not only `x,y,z` but also `w` and all it's values love only between `-1` and `1` => most probably not the value you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

```
    GameObject Temporary_Bullet_Handler = Instantiate(Bullet, attackPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(Random.Range(2.557f, -2.557f), Random.Range(0f, -5.795f), attackPoint.transform.rotation.z) as GameObject);
```

You are casting the Quaternion parameter of the Instantiate function into a GamObject. Remove the 'as GameObject' and it should be working.